# How can I roll back 1 file change in my previous commit

Tags: git

I have made 2 commits (And I have not pushed) in git, where 'Commit 2' is the most recent one':

```
 git log -2
commit 791962d776f66253d656586b097b2677eaa983d1
Author: michael <michael@michael-laptop.(none)>
Date:   Tue Jun 29 23:20:58 2010 -0700

    Commit 2

commit b743075e81f6fe25fe48ddbef2b5e7cc06623533
Author: michael <michael@michael-laptop.(none)>
Date:   Tue Feb 16 23:09:53 2010 -0800

    Commit 1
```

And in my commit 1 b743075e81f6fe25fe48ddbef2b5e7cc06623533, I touched/changed a number of files:

```
   dir1/file1.cpp
   dir1/file1.h
   dir1/file2.cpp
   dir1/file2.h
```

My questions is, how can I roll back my changes that I made to dir1/file2.cpp, dir1/file2.h of commit 1? And keep everything else the same?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest solution would be, from your latest commit (HEAD) to:

- [checkout](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) those two files at the older version,
- add them,
- and then commit.

```
    git checkout b743075e81 -- dir1/file2.cpp
    git checkout b743075e81 -- dir1/file2.h
    git add dir1/file2.cpp # only if you made additional changes
    git add dir1/file2.h   # only if you made additional changes
    git commit -m "revert dir1/file2.cpp and dir1/file2.h"
```

As [Chris Johnsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193688/chris-johnsen) mentions in the comments:

> **`git checkout` with pathspecs updates the index** (like `git reset` with pathspecs) and the working tree, so `git add` is not needed unless additional changes are made after the checkout.

Comment: This is in fact your only sane option, if you've already used `git push` to push your commits to the origin.

Comment: *git checkout* with pathspecs updates the index (like *git reset* with pathspecs) and the working tree, so *git add* is not needed unless additional changes are made after the checkout.

Comment: @michael: then the `git rebase --interactive` described in Blair's answer should interest you.

Answer (score 3):

If you've already pushed your commits to the origin, then the other solutions described here (using `git reset` or `git checkout`, followed by `git commit`) is your only sane option.

However, **if** you haven't pushed your changes yet, **and** you want to remove all traces that the files were ever committed, an interactive rebase is a good option. Use the following command to rebase your last two commits:

```
git rebase --interactive HEAD~2
```

An editor will open, showing your two commits. You want to edit the file to show the following, then save; particularly, you want to change `pick` in front of your first commit to `edit`:

```
edit b743075 Commit 1
pick 791962d Commit 2
```

Git will then place us into a state where we can edit the first commit (without touching the second). It says you can amend the commit with `git commit --amend`, but we actually want to do a reset to the commit before head, and undo it entirely:

```
git reset HEAD^
```

This will place the changes from Commit 1 back into your working tree. Then, `git add` only the files you want to keep, and re-commit them using `git commit`:

```
git add dir1/file1.cpp
git add dir1/file1.h
git commit -m "Commit 1"
```

Finally, do a hard reset to delete the files you don't want to keep from your working tree, and finish the rebase:

```
git reset --hard
git rebase --continue
```

When the rebase is complete, your repository will have both commits, but no traces of the `file2.*` files.

Answer (score 0):

Use following command to roll back the file with previously committed file based on the commit hash and filename which you need to revert

```
 git reset <commit hash> <filename>
```

For your requirement use

```
 git reset b743075e81f6fe25fe48ddbef2b5e7cc06623533 dir1/file2.cpp

 git reset b743075e81f6fe25fe48ddbef2b5e7cc06623533 dir1/file2.h
```

Comment: This works, but can be confusing because it only “rolls back” the index entries, not the working tree (unlike `git checkout treeish -- pathspecs` which updates both the index and the working tree).